# What are the region-space combinations that can be used for button and panel registration

Tags: python, scripting

What are the available regions, and also, which ones can have a button registered to?

---

While registering any panel we need to specify which space/region should be assigned to, in example: {space: VIEW_3D, region: UI}.

However not all regions are available for every space, and not all regions could have buttons/panels registered to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This table has all the space-region combinations that work.

[image]

Reference: [Blender Space-Regions guide](http://walidshouman.blogspot.de/2017/12/blender-spaces-and-regions.html)